# best way to calculate the first- and last-day of Week, Month and Year

Tags: java, date, calendar

He all,

I am trying to calculate the first- and last-day of Week, Month and Year.
For Month and Year it Works fine but week is wrong:

```java
public Date[] calcDateRange(Calendar c, int day) {
    Date[] dr = new Date[2];
    // setMin
    c.set(day, c.getActualMinimum(day));
    dr[0] = c.getTime();
    // setMax
    c.set(day, c.getActualMaximum(day));
    dr[1] = c.getTime();
    return dr;
}

public void print() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Calendar cStart = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    cStart.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out.println("startdate: " + sdf.format(cStart.getTime()));
    Date[] minMaxD = calcDateRange(cStart, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    System.out.println("start_of_week:\t" + sdf.format(minMaxD[0]) + "\nend_of_week:\t" + sdf.format(minMaxD[1]));
    minMaxD = calcDateRange(cStart, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println("start_of_month:\t" + sdf.format(minMaxD[0]) + "\nend_of_month:\t" + sdf.format(minMaxD[1]));
    minMaxD = calcDateRange(cStart, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    System.out.println("start_of_year:\t" + sdf.format(minMaxD[0]) + "\nend_of_year:\t" + sdf.format(minMaxD[1]));
}
```

Can someone help me to find my mistakes?
What is the best way to calculate the dates?

Output:

```
startdate: 20.03.2014
start_of_week:  23.03.2014 <--- wrong, should be '17.03.2014'
end_of_week:    22.03.2014 <--- wrong, should be '23.03.2014'
start_of_month: 01.03.2014
end_of_month:   31.03.2014
start_of_year:  01.01.2014
end_of_year:    31.12.2014
```

Thank you in advance.

**//edit**

Currently I use the following methode, but im not realy happy with it:

```
public Date[] calcDateRange(Calendar c, int day) {
    int fdow = c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
    Date[] dr = new Date[2];
    // setMin
    c.set(day, c.getActualMinimum(day));
    //..setSecondsMinutes
    if (day == Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        c.add(day, 1); // German Week correction
    dr[0] = c.getTime();

    // setMax
    c.set(day, c.getActualMaximum(day));
    //..setSecondsMinutes
    if (day == Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        c.add(day, 1); // German Week correction
    dr[1] = c.getTime();
    c.setFirstDayOfWeek(fdow);
    return dr;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joda Time library is useful for things around dates and times. As I cant comment yet I am posting it as an answer. I suggest you to look into it.
http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

**//EDIT:**

I think that I have found where is the mistake.
The start of the week is incorrect because:

You call

```
 Date[] minMaxD = calcDateRange(cStart, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

and then on the line in calcDateRange function

```
c.set(day, c.getActualMinimum(day));
```

the following will happen:

1. the day variable is an int with value 7
2. c.getActualMinimum(day) will return 1 because of the fact that getActualMinimum(7) method returns the minimum for field 7 which is "DAY_OF_WEEK" and the minimum for this field equals "SUNDAY" which is int with value 1
3. the you c.set(7,1) which will set the "DAY_OF_WEEK" as 1 ("SUNDAY")

On the

```
dr[0] = c.getTime();
```

line you will get time for SUNDAY because you set it and the date then returns 23.3.

Principal is the same for the end of week:

On the line

c.set(day, c.getActualMaximum(day));

you set "DAY_OF_WEEK" to SATURDAY and then it will return you date 22.3.

**//EDIT2:**
method for calculating start and end of week

```
public Date[] calcDateRangeWeek(Calendar c, int day) {
    Date[] dr = new Date[2];
    // setMin
    c.set(day, Calendar.MONDAY);
    dr[0] = c.getTime();
    // setMax
    c.set(day, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    dr[1] = c.getTime();
    return dr;
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try, but can someone explain why it doesnt work ?

Comment: even when `c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` return `MONDAY = 2` my method would not work

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Java 8, I would use the [TemporalAdjusters](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) from `java.time`:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import static java.time.DayOfWeek.*;
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.*;

    public void print() {
        DateTimeFormatter german = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.printf("startdate: %s%n", start.format(german));
        System.out.printf("start_of_week:\t%s%nend_of_week:\t%s%n",
                start.with(previousOrSame(MONDAY)).format(german),
                start.with(nextOrSame(SUNDAY)).format(german));
        System.out.printf("start_of_month:\t%s%nend_of_month:\t%s%n",
                start.with(firstDayOfMonth()).format(german),
                start.with(lastDayOfMonth()).format(german));
        System.out.printf("start_of_year:\t%s%nend_of_year:\t%s%n",
                start.with(firstDayOfYear()).format(german),
                start.with(lastDayOfYear()).format(german));
    }
```

If you can't use Java 8, these features all come from the Joda Time library.

Comment: good to know, but i cannot use Java8, i will give Joda Time lib a try

Comment: I think the only difference with Joda Time would be the package names. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Calendar like this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = cal.getTime();

cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
Date mondayOfTheWeek = cal.getTime();

....
```

The calendar recalculate the associated Date automatically

EDIT: for the last day of the month

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
```

And you can do the same with Calendar.YEAR and Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR